# Run window.addEventListener Function only once

Tags: jquery

I have this function which runs a video when I scroll to it:

```
var _video = document.getElementById('video-one');

function isScrolledIntoView(element) {
  var elementTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    elementBottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  return elementTop >= 0 && elementBottom <= window.innerHeight;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(_video)) {
    _video.play();
  }
});
```

Problem is, after the video stops and I scroll away and back to it - it runs again. But I need it to run only once, only the first time I scroll to it.
I tried flagging the function to run once, but it doesn't work:

```
var _video = document.getElementById('video-one');

function isScrolledIntoView(element) {
  var elementTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    elementBottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  return elementTop >= 0 && elementBottom <= window.innerHeight;
}

var started = false;
if (!started) {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(_video)) {
      _video.play();
    }
  });
  started = false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to pass exact the same arguments in case to remove eventListener. This method have to solve the problem. The reason is that removeEventListener takes all of it's arguments from argument list of the handler.

---

I've changed the eventPhase to TRUE and it works.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if (isScrolledIntoView(_video)) {
        _video.play();
        this.removeEventListener(e.type,arguments.callee,e.eventPhase);
    }
}, true); // CHANGED HERE!!!!
```

Comment: I don't want a click. I just want this to happen the first time I scroll and not other times.

Comment: Changed the answer

Comment: Hmm.. still if i scroll away and back, the video plays

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: removeEventListener is not enough to understand what it does?

Comment: still :/ check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/doe8jtw6/

Comment: I saved the new variant in the jsfiddle (if it is polite to do so). The mistake was FALSE to eventPhase - turned to true. Video doesn't stop but doesn't play again too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with "jquery" (though I see no jquery code), I will give you a jquery answer :)

```
function videoScroll() {
    if ($('#video-one').visible(true)) {
        videoPlay();
    }
}

function videoPlay() {
    $(window).off("scroll", videoScroll());
    $("#video-one").play();
}

$(window).on("scroll", videoScroll());
```

Comment: Didn't work, the video didnt even begin to play on scroll

Comment: Is jQuery in scope?   If yes, maybe .visible() isn't working as I expect.   Oh well, looks like the other guy got you sorted out.   Best!